Disable Content but Enable Scrolling
I am attempting to attach a modifier to a ScrollView that still allows scrolling and disables all the underlying buttons:
struct ContentView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewButtonDisableView()
            .modifier(ScrollHitModifier())
    }
}

struct ScrollViewButtonDisableView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0...100, id: \.self) { buttonNumber in
                    Button("Press \(buttonNumber)") {
                        print("Button number \(buttonNumber) pressed")
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ScrollHitModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .allowsHitTesting(false)
    }
}

Unfortunately the result is that both the buttons and the scrolling do not work any more. I still want to be able to scroll.
I know that I can add the modifier ScrollHitModifier() to the VStack in ScrollViewButtonDisableView, but that defeats the purpose of what I am looking for. I would like to add a modifier to the overall struct and not have to place it into the struct.
Is there any way to attach an .allowsHitTesting modifier to the ScrollViewButtonDisableView and still allow scrolling?

You could add a dummy TapGesture as a .highPriorityGesture to the ScrollView. This blocks tap gestures on the content inside the ScrollView, but still allows scrolling to be performed.
EDIT Adding .including: .gesture seems to help to prevent gestures from reaching the subviews (ref. comments). The documentation for this GestureMask states:

Enable the added gesture but disable all gestures in the subview hierarchy.

...which is just what's needed!
struct ScrollHitModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .highPriorityGesture(
                TapGesture(),
                including: .gesture
            )
    }
}


That’s a really neat workaround! One minor issue - when I tap on a button if flickers very slightly. Seems as if the button first reacts and then the gesture overrides it and shuts it off. All within a fraction of a second. Any ideas on turning off that behavior?

@Pete Runniing on an iPhone 15 simulator with iOS 17.4, I don't see the button-press effect that you're describing. Which environment are you running with?

Running on iPhone simulator 15 pro with iOS 17.4, M2 max. The button press effect is very subtle and only happens once on each button after scrolling and the view has to rebuild. I also checked it on my iPhone 15 pro max - same effect.

@Pete I couldn't see it for a simple tap (I tried with dark and light modes, also tried with button shapes enabled -> no tap effect perceivable). However, I did see a change of color with a small drag gesture, so maybe this was kicking in? In any case, adding .including: .gesture seems to help. The .onEnded callback can be omitted too. Answer updated.

Works perfectly now, the .including completely turns the flicker off! Brilliant solution.
